# To solve pi raised to the power of e and vice versa using Python

Tags: python-3.x

How i can solve pi raised to the power of  e and vice versa using Python ?
I used pow() first and the replaced it with ** I have got 45.something ,I think it is wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

`math.pi**math.e` returns 22.45915771836104

`math.e**math.pi` and `math.exp(math.pi)` both return 23.140692632779263

Also, "calculate" is a term better than "solve".